# qemu not working after installation in ubuntu

Tags: 15.04, qemu

I intstalled qemu in ubuntu to execute a kernel .bin file using it. It installed properly. After that when i type
   qemu -kernel kernel.bin
It shows qemu not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You can try for ex.

```
qemu-x86_64 -kernel kernel.bin
```

It's the qemu command for 64-bit systems.

After typing

```
qemu
```

you can try completing your command with 'Tab' key and see if the system sees the qemu at all :-)

Comment: Its not working my kernel.bin is 32 bit file

Comment: So maybe try a qemu-i386 or qemu-system-i386?

Answer (score 0):

Using 32-bit the following worked for me:

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel kernel.bin
```